# Do we have Test explorer in VS code for Protractor Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, visual-studio-code, protractor, karma-jasmine

I'm working in Protractor Jasmine framework in node js.

Do we have test explorer or any plugin which lists all the TCs in the spec-.ts files of the project? So that we can execute the test directly from the test exlporer?

We have test explorer in Visual studio. Same way is it available in VS code?

Thanks In advance